# Vue: Limiting users with certain roles have access to certain pages in the router vue-element-admin

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm using vue-admin-template that can be seen here: https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-admin-template.

I has a permission based system that allows you to limit the user's access according to their roles. I can limit what the user sees by adding the following code inside the pages:

```
<template>
  <div v-permission="['admin']">
    <h1>You are the admin</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import permission from '@/directive/permission/index.js'

export default {
  name: 'ThePage',
  directives: { permission },
```

The vue-admin-template has a router system that lists all the pages that you can access on the side menu that looks like this:

```
export const constantRoutes = [
{
    path: '/test1',
    component: Layout,
    redirect: '/',
    name: 'Test',
    alwaysShow: false,
    hidden: true,
    meta: { roles: ['admin'], title: 'Test', icon: 'example' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'inside',
        props: true,
        name: 'Inside',
        component: () => import('@/views/test/index'),
        meta: { title: 'Inside', icon: 'peoples' },
        hidden: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately if a user does not have the roll of admin, he/she can still see access this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not clear to me but there are 2 const areas that the routes can be added to:

constantRoutes
and
asyncRoutes

If you want to use the users roles to determine what they can see your entries has to be in the **asyncRoutes**

````
export const asyncRoutes = [
{
    path: '/test1',
    component: Layout,
    redirect: '/',
    name: 'Test',
    alwaysShow: false,
    hidden: true,
    meta: { roles: ['admin'], title: 'Test', icon: 'example' },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'inside',
        props: true,
        name: 'Inside',
        component: () => import('@/views/test/index'),
        meta: { title: 'Inside', icon: 'peoples' },
        hidden: true
      }
    ]
  }
}```
````